# How to solve overdetermined system of equations in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

my problem is the following.
Using *linsolve* function I am solving an overdetermined matrix *200x50* with very similar elements. Because of this, the solution that I get is not correct. Maybe some of you would have any suggestions how to solve such a system?

Best wishes,

Valerie

Comment: Your system is over-determined. What are you expecting your answer to be? Can you provide more information about the inputs?

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that your system does not have a solution.

Rather than attempting to solve the system `A*x=b`, the next best thing you can do is to solve a similar problem:

```
min norm(A*x-b)
```

When the norm used is the [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm), the solution to the minimization problem is called a "[Least-Squares solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares)"

The MATLAB syntax is:

```
x = A\b
```